# Sending a string with commas from asp.net to Oracle seems to cause an issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

On my front end, I'm sending VarChar variables to be used in a Stored Procedure in Oracle.  My front end code looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection conn = GetConnection();

    try
    {
        {
            string vw_AuditID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["AuditID"]);
            string vw_PlanID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["PlanID"]);

            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCST"].ToString();
            OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand();
            cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd3.CommandText = "CSTAPP_O.CST_ADMIN_REPORT";
            cmd3.Connection = conn;

            cmd3.Parameters.Add("RAudit", OracleType.VarChar).Value = vw_AuditID;
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("RPlan", OracleType.VarChar).Value = vw_PlanID;
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("cursor_", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            var SearchAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd3);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            SearchAdapter.Fill(ds);

            // Perform the binding.
            GridView_AuditReport.DataSource = ds;
            GridView_AuditReport.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the error
        Console.WriteLine("Error making Call to " + ex + "");
    }
}
```

Note that AuditID and PlanID are coming from a previous page, and are passed like 
    ?AuditID='10294'&PlanID='322, 323, 324'

On the Oracle side, I'm running a stored procedure like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "CST_ADMIN_REPORT" 
(
    RAudit VARCHAR2,
    RPlan VARCHAR2,
    cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
open cursor_ for

SELECT BLAH // Edited the lengthy SELECT section out, no need for it.
Where FAP.Audit_ID = RAudit
AND FAP.Plan_ID in (RPlan)
ORDER BY FAP.PLAN_DESC ASC;

END CST_ADMIN_REPORT;
```

So, if I pass one Plan ID, it runs perfectly fine.  However, if I pass multiple PlanIDs (such as '322, 323, 324'), the Oracle procedure tells me the number is invalid.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with the way I'm passing the info to Oracle?

Comment: When you say "front end code" and then you mix database access into it, I cringe. Database access doesn't below directly in your code behind - it should be in a separate layer. And you need to learn how to handle [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) properly (your OracleConnection).

Comment: Like I explained in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568817/how-would-you-get-the-value-from-request-querystringtext), do separate your problems. This problem has either got to do with query strings or with Oracle, not both. Query strings don't know about Oracle, nor vice versa. This is all about strings, so trim your question down to a [mcve]. I also explained to post errors verbatim, not your interpretation. _"the Oracle procedure tells me the number is invalid"_ is not a verbatim error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT BLAH // Edited the lengthy SELECT section out, no need for it.
Where FAP.Audit_ID = RAudit
AND FAP.Plan_ID in (RPlan)
ORDER BY FAP.PLAN_DESC ASC;
```

`RPlan` is a bind variable and is a single value - even though you are putting in a comma delimited string it is still a single value and it is trying to match the numeric value in your `Plan_ID` column to a string containing numbers and commas and is effectively doing:

```
AND TO_CHAR( FAP.Plan_ID ) = '322,323,324'
```

which is not going to generate a match.

If you want to pass in an array then use a collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IntList IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/
```

and pass that into the procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CST_ADMIN_REPORT
(
    RAudit  IN  FAP.Audit_ID%TYPE,
    RPlan   IN  IntList,
    cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
  open cursor_ for
    SELECT BLAH // Edited the lengthy SELECT section out, no need for it.
    Where FAP.Audit_ID = RAudit
    AND FAP.Plan_ID MEMBER OF RPlan
    ORDER BY FAP.PLAN_DESC ASC;
END CST_ADMIN_REPORT;
```

However, you might find that the C# driver only supports passing [associative arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB) (rather than collections) so you might need to pass in an associative array (which can be used in PL/SQL but not in SQL) and copy the values into a collection which you can then use in an SQL statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CST_ADMIN_PKG
IS
  TYPE IntAssocArrayType IS TABLE OF INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  PROCEDURE CST_ADMIN_REPORT
  (
    RAudit  IN  FAP.Audit_ID%TYPE,
    RPlan   IN  IntAssocArrayType,
    cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  );
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CST_ADMIN_PKG
IS
  PROCEDURE CST_ADMIN_REPORT
  (
    RAudit  IN  FAP.Audit_ID%TYPE,
    RPlan   IN  IntAssocArrayType, -- Pass assoc. array in.
    cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  AS
    -- Create a collection
    p_rplan IntList := IntList(); 
    i       PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    -- Copy assoc. array into the collection
    i := RPlan.FIRST:
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      p_rplan.EXTEND;
      p_rplan(p_rplan.COUNT) := RPlan(i);
      i := RPlan.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;

    open cursor_ for
      SELECT BLAH
      Where FAP.Audit_ID = RAudit
      AND FAP.Plan_ID MEMBER OF p_RPlan -- Use the collection in the select.
      ORDER BY FAP.PLAN_DESC ASC;
  END CST_ADMIN_REPORT;
END;
/
```

Comment: I am consistently amazed and humbled by the knowledge some people possess.  I would have never figured this out with what little I know about Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't accept a string in that `in (RPlan)` clause. Not sure if it's the best solution, but you can parse the parameter string like that:

```
in (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(RPlan,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
    FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(RPlan, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```